# how do I pass an array to the View from the controller?

Tags: javascript, php, model-view-controller

If the values entered in the fields are incorrect, an error should be output, which is written to the array in the Controller and given to the View. The value in array is recorded, but the View does not show it. I understand that some kind of reload is needed, but how to write it?

controller_login.php

```
class controller_login extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = new model_login();
        $this->view = new View();
    }
    function action_index()
    {
        $this->pageData['title'] = "Sign In";
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            $action = $_POST['action'];

            if ($action == 'login') {
                if (!$this->model->entry()) {
                    $this->pageData['loginError'] = "Incorrect login or password"; 
                    $this->view->non_template("login_view.php", $this->pageData);
                }
                echo json_encode([
                  'res' => $this->model->entry(),     
                ]);
            }
        } else {
            $this->view->non_template("login_view.php", $this->pageData); // here
        }
    }
}
```

login_view.php

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">
                    <?php if (!empty($pageData['loginError'])) : ?>
                        <p class="color-red"><?php echo $pageData['loginError']; ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

model_login.php

```
class model_login extends Model
{
    public function entry(): bool
    {
        $login = $_POST['login'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE login = :login AND password = :password";

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':login', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        $res = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if (!empty($res)) {
            setcookie('user', $res['login'], strtotime('+30 days'));
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

js

```
function loginFormSend(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(loginForm);

    const res = fetch('/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data,
    })
    res
    .then(i => i?.res && location.reload())       
    .then(i => i?.res || location.reload());
}
```

Comment: You should also load `view` after you assign the 'loginError' info

Comment: @JunPan I added load `view`  but it didn't help  `$this->pageData['loginError'] = "Incorrect login or password"; $this->view->non_template("login_view.php", $this->pageData);`

Comment: What does `!$this->model->entry()` mean? Have you debugged using `echo` some variables to figure out which line the problem is?

Comment: @JunPan I edited my question. Please take a look at this. I hope it will be more clear now

Comment: If you can get the response in the front, then you can show it to DOM via js.